# How do I find out the commit Id of an annotated tag on the remote using LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: tags, libgit2sharp

Using repo.Network.ListReferences provides me the TargetIdentifier of the reference, but in case of annotated tag, that points to the ObjectId of the tag. How do I find out the CommitId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to retrieve the target of an annotated tag by only leveraging `repo.Network.ListReferences`.

You'll first have to fetch those locally, either by:

- Retrieving all the tags (only the new/updated ones will be retrieved). See this **[test](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/FetchFixture.cs#L68-L101)** for some guidance.
- Selecting the ones you're interested with and leveraging the lower-level `Fetch()` overload which accepts a collection of refspecs and passing `new[]{ "refs/tags/v0.1:refs/tags/v0.1", "refs/tags/v1.32:refs/tags/v1.32" }`, for instance. See this **[test](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/FetchFixture.cs#L103-L134)** for some guidance about fetching custom refspecs.

> How do I find out the CommitId?

- Once the references are fetched, locally resolve the tag (eg. `Tag myTag = repo.Tags["v1.32"];`).
- When the tag is annotated (ie. not a lightweight tag), the `myTag.IsAnnotated` property will be set to `true` and the `myTag.Annotation.Target` will point to the `GitObject` pointed at by the tag.

If the retrieved GitObject is a `Commit`, accessing its `Id` property should answer your question.

Beware that, although not that a frequent case, a tag may point to something else than a `Commit`. For instance a `Blob`, or a `Tree`. One may even find, in the wild, chained annotated tags (in which case, you'll have to recursively resolve the `Target` of each `TagAnnotation` until it's no longer a `TagAnnotation`.

FWIW, there's a **[open up-for-grabs issue](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/551)** about exposing a friendlier way to retrieve the final peeled target.

See the **[TagFixture.cs](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/TagFixture.cs)** test suite for a more comprehensive view of tag manipulation with LibGit2Sharp.